# Adding a string to Resources will not be recognized in xaml editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to add multiple languages to my WPF program. So I use Properties.Resources to store all visible strings.

In my XAML I have

```
<Window x:Class="DCMarker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:DCMarker.Properties"
        Title="{x:Static loc:Resources.Title}" Height="534.6" Width="612" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closed="Window_Closed"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Menu Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static loc:Resources.Tools}">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ToolsConnect" Header="{x:Static loc:Resources.ToolsConnect}" Click="ToolsConnect_Click" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ToolsDisconnect" Header="{x:Static loc:Resources.ToolsDisconnect}" Click="ToolsDisconnect_Click" />
                    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ToolsOptions" Header="{x:Static loc:Resources.ToolsOptions}" Click="ToolsOptions_Click" />
    </MenuItem>
```

But If I add a string to Resources this string will not be recognized by the XAML editor (or maybe Intellisence). Usually if I rebuild the solution they will be recognized but sometimes i have to restart VS2013.

Anyone have a clue why and how to fix this?

// anders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StaticExtension` class will only find public members and unfortunately when the code behind for the `Resources.resx` file is generated, the properties that retrieve the resources are marked `internal`.

To resolve this limitation you could go to your Resource' properties and change the “**Custom Tool**” from `ResXFileCodeGenerator` to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`, then compile your solution and try again.

Comment: I had changed the resources to public but the Custom Tool was set to ResXFileCodeGenerator... Fixed now! Thank you!!